# How to get value of function in select statement

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I created this function

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_getMemberFee]
    (@mem_id numeric(8,2))  
RETURNS MONEY
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @fee MONEY

    EXEC p_calc_member_fee @mem_id, @memberFee = @fee OUTPUT; 

    RETURN (@fee)
END
```

but there is error when I tried to get value from the function

```
select dbo.fn_getMemberFee (49834)
```

Error:

> Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

May I know why?

Thank you

Comment: @John, technically it's possible using master..xp_cmdshell, but not desirable and not safe, so it is better to convert this function to SP.

Comment: I know. , That's why I deleted my comment seconds after submitting.  One can  erase one's shame